# Posts per page, reverse count

Tags: posts

Let's say I have 10 posts on my blog with a posts per page limit of 7, this is what I get:

- Page 1(home): 7 posts
- Page 2: 3 posts

But I need this:

- Page 1(home): 3 posts
- Page 2: 7 posts

I need to start posts from the last page, any idea on how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind the cost of calling `COUNT` to first get the total number of posts (you have a dynamic first page in terms of numbers of posts so it doesn't work with a simple offset) here is something that I've wrote (it's late and I am tired so it might have some bugs / might not be the right solution):

```
// This code can be placed in the 'functions.php' file.
function wt_posts_clauses_hook( $clauses, $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_home() ) {
        global $wpdb;

        extract( $clauses );

        if ( ! empty( $groupby ) ) $groupby = 'GROUP BY ' . $groupby;

        $sql = "SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM $wpdb->posts $join WHERE 1=1 $where $groupby";
        $no_posts = $wpdb->get_var( $sql );
        $posts_per_page = get_option( 'posts_per_page' );
        $extra = $no_posts % $posts_per_page;
        $paged = absint( $query->get( 'paged' ) );

        if ( ! $paged ) $paged = 1;

        $from = ( $paged - 1 ) * $posts_per_page;
        $to = $posts_per_page;

        if ( $extra ) {
            if ( $paged < 2 ) {
                $from = 0;
                $to = $extra;
            } else {
                $from = $posts_per_page * ( $paged - 2 ) + $extra;
            }
        }           

        $clauses['limits'] = "LIMIT {$from}, {$to}";
    }

    return $clauses;
}
add_filter( 'posts_clauses_request', 'wt_posts_clauses_hook', 99, 2 );
```

You can probably implement a caching mechanism if you don't want to run this on every listing page call by reading the `found_posts` property. If it doesn't correspond to the cache entry you simply delete the cache. Of course, you first have to modify this function above to initially try and read the `$no_posts` value from cache. If there is none then run the `$sql` query and create the cache with the corresponding `$no_posts` value.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, I'm a total newbie to WP, where exacly should I put this piece of code? Inside which file?

Comment: This would go in the `functions.php` file.

Comment: So, I put this code inside my functions.php and my site crashes...

Comment: As of now, I have tested this code on the following WordPress themes: `Twenty Fifteen`, `Twenty Fourteen` and `Twenty Thirteen`. The code requires PHP version >= 5.3.0 which was launched almost 6 years ago. Perhaps that is the issue. I will update the code and remove the closure, hopefully this will fix your issue.

Comment: Just one pro tip, never ever use `extract()`. It was removed from core and the codex for very specific reasons. It is unreliable and almost impossible to debug

Comment: @PieterGoosen I would say that using `extract` is bad in most cases but not in a controlled situation like this: a closed scope which doesn't include other templates and it also operates on specific data passed by that core WordPress filter. Also, `extract` (native PHP fun, why should it be mentioned on the WordPress Codex?) is still used in at least [one place in the core](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-includes/template.php#L547). Otherwise, I agree, [it can be dangerous sometimes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php#refsect1-function.extract-notes) to use it.

Comment: @webtoure Yes, the problem might be PHP as I have 5.2.*

Comment: Hmm, so my hunch was right after all. :) You can test this version and let me know if you have issues.

Comment: @webtoure Tested it now, works perfectly. Thank you!